# inserting python calendar into tkinter label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've a problem with the code that I have written. When I insert the variable `calendar2019` into the tkinter label `LabelCalen` it does not show up in the window `root4`, and the window `root4` is not created at all.

```
import calendar
import tkinter as tk

def CalScr():
    calendar2019 = calendar.calendar(2019)#creating calender variable
    root4 = tk.Tk()
    labelCalen= tk.Label(root4, text = calendar2019, )
    root4.mainloop
CalScr()
```

the calender should be printed out in the label `LabelCalen`

Comment: Do you want a calender sort of like datepicker in your tk window?

Comment: shouldn't mainloop be called as a method?  What is the return from CalScr()?

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems is that you are not invoking `mainloop` as you omitted the `()`. The other is you are not giving the label a position.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import calendar
import tkinter as tk
def CalScr():
    calendar2019 = calendar.calendar(2019) #creating calender variable
    root4 = tk.Tk()
    labelCalen= tk.Label(root4, text = calendar2019, font=("Courier New", 14))
    labelCalen.grid(column=0, row=0)
    root4.mainloop()
CalScr()
```

This is also setting the font to a fixed space one otherwise the calendar won't be aligned properly.